# How to add data in ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase many to many table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, postgresql, arcgis-10.5

I have 3 tables in my PostgreSQL geodatabase. I am using ArcGIS 10.5

- parcel
- owner
- parcel_to_owner

`parcel_to_owner` is many to many table that created using ArcGIS. `parcel_to_owner` table has 3 columns named `rid, parcel_id, owner_id`

So I want to add data in this table using sql.

I can generate the objectid for parcel feature using `sde.next_rowid('sde','parcel')`. But if I use `sde.next_rowid('sde','parcel_to_owner')` it generates big numbers. For example, if next rid value is 7, it generates 685.
But how can I add next `rid` value?

Comment: It appears that you have loaded your data as the `sde` login. Doing so increases the chance of catastrophic damage to your database integrity. Your first task is to create additional logins, users that match the login names, and schemas that match the user name. It doesn't matter what they're named (well, except that they can't be reserved words), but there should be at least two of them, one to own the data, and the second for read-only or read-write access. IDs are allocated only once (never reused). The only way to generate smaller numbers is to start over.

Comment: I have created the tables using sde user and added sample data rows. All other users have their own users. Is this a problem? I have gisviewer and giseditor users. So I am adding users to these groups. And I am adding privilages prom arccatalog.

Comment: If you CREATE tables as `sde`, you'll be tempted to DROP tables as `sde`, and doing that could corrupt the geodatabase beyond recovery. Treat the 'sde' user as if it were `postgres` (only use it when no other option exists, which means during version management and upgrade)